# Odoo 10 .csv file import

Tags: csv, odoo

I'm trying to import data into a module I created in Odoo. However, here is what comes out of it:

[image]

Do you know the reason?

It is a file containing 400 lines, I tried to reduce the import with 50 lines is the same error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error normally happens when the source code of Odoo is modified or import fields are not correct. you can refer this [link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/11512).

please try to import sample data with some fields.